# Ruby не выводит элемент массива, если содержимое элемента в другой кодировке

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Получаю из LDAP группу и смотрю, какие пользователи присутствуют в ней. Ответ приходит в виде массива.

```
  ldap.search( :base => tbs, :filter => flt1)do |entry|
    logger.info "Name: #{entry.name} Inspect: #{entry.inspect}".
    m = entry.try(:member)
    if( m )
      logger.info "Members: #{m.size}  #{m}".
      logger.info "Member 0: #{m[0]} ".
      logger.info "Member 1: #{m[1]} ".
      m.each {|i| logger.info "#{i}"}
    else
      logger.info "Members: Nil!"
    end
  end
```

Если массив пустой (группа пустая), то отрабатывает корректно, выводит "Members: Nil!". Если не пустой, то отказывается выводить нулевой элемент массива (хоть по индексу [0], хоть перебором each), но весь массив выводит и там этот нулевой элемент есть:

```
Name: ["R_Users"] Inspect: #<Net::LDAP::Entry:0x00000004e2a1e0 @myhash={:dn=>["CN=R_Users,OU=Linux,OU=Roles,OU=...]}
Members: 2  ["CN=\xD0\xA1\xD0\xBC,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ru", "CN=Familiya IO,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ru"]
Member 1: CN=Familiya IO,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ru
CN=Familiya IO,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ru
```

Вопрос похоже смещается в область кодировок. Попробовал вытащить состав других групп. Если имя CN в английской раскладке, то все ок, если в русской, то тут наступают проблемы... LDAP - AD от Microsoft, сервер приложений - CentOS 7, локаль UTF-8.
Но что интересно, если вывести отдельно этот текст - все ок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решается элементарно: метод force_encoding

```
 logger.info "Member 0: #{m[0].force_encoding('utf-8')} "
 logger.info "Member 1: #{m[1].force_encoding('utf-8')} "
```

Только предусмотреть проверку на Nil